# Running two shell commands using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.02

Tags: python-3.x, shell, ubuntu, terminal

In order to get some software running I need to 1. Run a script that will execute a remote license manage, 2. Execute a shell script to start the software.  I can do this by opening a command window in the directory with the rlm , and then type ./rlm to run the Linux executable.  Then I can go into the directory that contains the shell script, open a terminal in that location and run ./myshell.sh.  This opens the GUI for my software.

I would like to run these steps using a single Python script.  I have tried:

```
#change the working directory...    
os.chdir(r'/opt/mysoftwarelocation') 
#confirm location change...
print(os.getcwd() )
#run ./rlm...
os.system('./rlm')
```

At this point I can see from a python terminal that the rlm is running.

I would then like to run the code below to run the shell script...

```
os.chdir(r'/opt/mysoftwarelocation/sumsubdirectory')
print(os.getcwd() )
os.system('./some.sh')
```

Unfortunately, after os.system('./rlm') finishes the script stalls and will not execute further and without an errors.
How to I get the second part  of my script to run within a single Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the rlm command in the background?
**subprocess** module gives a nice interface for that

Comment: Thanks, but the same thing happens when I run rlm via subprocess.run([./rlm']).  I edited my post.  The script does not quit after rlm it just stalls once the rlm runs.  Maybe there is a way to open a second os terminal?

Comment: os.system() waits until the command finishes,thats why it stalls. Hence I recommended using as a background function